# What's wrong with my CRC-12 implementation?

Tags: objective-c, c, crc

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to match http://zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html all the time.

```
short crcTable[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    int crc = (i << 4);
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        crc = (crc << 1) ^ ((crc & 0x800) ? 0x80F : 0);
    }
    crcTable[i] = crc & 0xFFF;
}


NSString *theString = @"blah";

unsigned char *string = (unsigned char *)[theString UTF8String];
int length = [theString length];

unsigned short crc = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    crc = crcTable[(crc ^ string[i]) & 255] ^ (crc >> 8);
}

NSLog(@"%X", crc);
```

One of our implementations is incorrect, I'm assuming it's mine.  But I have no idea what's wrong, or really how to go about working out what's wrong.  Any help'd be much appreciated.

Alec

Comment: When you call `[theString length]`, it gives you the length of the UTF-16 string, not the length of the UTF-8 string.  They will often be different.  You must use `strlen` to get the length of the UTF-8 string or some other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Replace

```
crc = crcTable[(crc ^ string[i]) & 255] ^ (crc >> 8);
```

by

```
 crc = crcTable[(crc >> 4) ^ string[i]] ^ (crc << 8);
```

2 Do mirror the 8 bits of each of the message's bytes before using them to calculate the crc value.

3 Finally mirror the 12 bits of the final `crc`.

As an alternative to the last mod you could also just do a `crc & 0xfff` and tell the breitbandkatze to 'reverse data bytes'.

Comment: Afraid not.  That returns values greater than 4,096 which I think is CRC-12's limit.

Comment: Another guess would be: `crc = crcTable[((crc >> 4) ^ string[i]) & 255] ^ (crc << 8);` I'll take a bet that's it! ;-)

Comment: Nope! :( That too returns values greater than 4,096.  I'm a bit lost.  I got a few implementations off the internet, this one was the only one that seemed to be anywhere near right as it gets *some* values right, just not all. Which completely confuses me. Thanks for the suggestions though, keep the guesses coming!

Comment: This is a little bit of an assumption but it seems to be incorrect when the output is above 0x800.  It might not be 0x800, but it's around that.  When http://zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html gives the output larger then that my implementation seems to go wrong.  Somewhere.

Comment: I just edited my answer to describe the final solution. (so the comments above might read somewhat confusing ... )

Comment: I've tried implementing the bit mirroring but I can't seem to get it outputting the correct value.  Should I be mirroring the 12 bits, the first 8 bits then the second 8 bits, or all 16 bits?

Comment: I changed my answer to be more prciese on what to mirror.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you I got something mixed up (it somehow seemed to have been to late when I wrote this). It's obviously not the `crcTable` entries which need to be mirrored but the message's data bytes.

Comment: I let go of masking with 255 as this is simply redundant work.

Comment: To summarise: 1 You calcuate the crc-table entries correctly. 2 There are two errors in the way you calculate the crc-value itself (see my answer). 3 The bit ordering of the messages you use does not match the bit ordering the breitbandkatze is using to calculate the crc value. The latter I would not consider an error but more question of the convention how to number the bits in a message.

Comment: Thanks for your help alk, I've corrected the calculation bit, but the mirroring I can't quite seem to get working correctly so have left.  As you said, it's not an error just a matter of convention, so I'm happy with it.  I will be the only one generating and checking this checksum so as the mirroring isn't hugely important, but this was a nice exercise!

Comment: Can you repost your working code on gist? What would you do to make it CRC8?

Comment: @DogEatDog: All mod/s necessary to make the OP's code work are mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @DogEatDog: You have an CRC8 implementation, that does now work?

Comment: @alk: Thanks, I translated this simple CRC8 algo to Objective C from VB. CRC is not a strong point for me. The values are hard coded. Please take a look. (this works by the way). How can i use yours to perform the following gist?

[CRC8 gist by me](https://gist.github.com/1952416) (i would like to make this better, but still keep it simple. )

[Original I found](http://avrhelp.mcselec.com/index.html?crc8.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to double check, but it appears you are building your table with big-endian code and calculating your CRC with little-endian code.

Try replacing this:

```
crc = crcTable[(crc ^ string[i]) & 255] ^ (crc >> 8);
```

with this:

```
crc = crc ^ (string[i] << 4);
```

```
crc = (crcTable[(crc >> 4) & 0xFF] ^ (crc << 4)) & 0xFFF;
```

-Jesse